# cellprofiler install will not run - version conflict

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im trying to run the bioimaging analysis package 'cell profiler' on Ubuntu 16.04, following the source installation instructions provided by the developers:

https://github.com/CellProfiler/CellProfiler/wiki/Source-installation-(Ubuntu-16.04-LTS)

However when I attempt to run cellprofiler from terminal, i encounter the following error code, which seems to be telling me there is a version conflict of matplotlib. Cell profiler seems to be running using python2.7, not python3.6 which is also set up on this machine, so this could be the source of the problem?

Error message in full:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cellprofiler", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3112, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3096, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3125, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 580, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 593, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (matplotlib 1.5.1 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('matplotlib>=2.0.0'), set(['scikit-image']))
```

Answer (score 0):

It says your `matplotlib` is version 1.5.1 when the library you're trying to install requires at least 2.0.0 version.
Try `pip install -U matplotlib`

Comment: Thanks Ricky: You are right in that the matplotlib version is part of the issue, however I think the root cause is that cellprofiler is attempting to run using an old python2.7 install, whereas the version of python that I use is 3.6.... I'm unsure how to remedy this however

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Cellprofiler is still using Python 2.7. They will transition to Python 3 with the newest version (CP 4.0). So at the moment you can not run it with python 3

Comment: Just an update on this... CP3 now requires Python >3.7

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Anja CellProfiler requires Python 2.7. When I installed CellProfiler on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine running Python 3.6, I created an virtual environment for CellProfiler with Python 2.7 and installed all required packages into this environment.

You can find a detailed description how to do this here:
https://github.com/CellProfiler/CellProfiler/wiki/Conda-Installation

By following this approach you can run CellProfiler with Python 2.7 via the virtual environment while you are still able to use Python 3.6 for your other applications/projects as before.